# Loading data into Google Colab from a central data repository?

Tags: google-colaboratory

What's the best place to upload data for use in Google Colaboratory notebooks? I'm planning to make some notebooks that load netCDF data using python, and I'd like to be able to send the notebooks to other people and have them load the same data without difficulty.

I know I can load data from my own Google Drive, but if I sent other people the notebooks, then I'd have to send them the data files too, right?

Is it possible to have a central data repository that multiple people can load data from? The files that I'd like to use are ~10-100 MB. I only need to read data, not write it. Thanks!